# the type must implement the inherited abstract method

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I am working on a program for intermediate Java and I am I feel I have the logic right, however I get this error in the class introduction:

> The type QuestionSet must implement the inherited abstract method
>   IQuestionSet.add(IQuestion)

I do have the method but I have a Question object for the parameter instead of IQuestion(The Interface for Question)

QuestionSet:

```
package com.jsoftware.test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuestionSet implements Serializable, IQuestionSet{

    ArrayList<Question> test = new ArrayList<Question>();

    public QuestionSet emptyTestSet(){
        QuestionSet set = new QuestionSet();
        return set;
    }
    public QuestionSet randomSample(int size){
        QuestionSet set = new QuestionSet();
        if(size>test.size()-1){
            for(int i =1; i<test.size(); i++){
                int num = (int)(Math.random()*test.size());
                set.add(test.get(num));
            }
        }else{
            for(int i =1; i<size; i++){
                int num = (int)(Math.random()*test.size());
                set.add(test.get(num));
            }
        }
        return set;
    }
    public boolean add(Question q){
        try{
            test.add(q);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean remove(int index){
        try{
            test.remove(index);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
    public Question getQuestion(int index){
        return test.get(index);
    }
    public int size(){
        return test.size();
    }


}
```

IQuestionSet:

```
package com.jsoftware.test;

/**
 * This interface represents a set of question. 
 * 
 * @author thaoc
 */
public interface IQuestionSet {

    /**
     * Create an empty test set.
     * @return  return an instance of a test set.
     */
    public IQuestionSet emptyTestSet();

    /**
     * return a test set consisting of a random questions.
     * @param size The number of random questions.
     * @return The test set instance containing the random questions.
     */
    public IQuestionSet randomSample(int size);

    /**
     * add a question to the test set.  
     * @param question The question
     * @return True if successful.
     */
    public boolean add(IQuestion question);

    /**
     * 
     * @param index Remove question using index
     * @return  true if index is valid
     */
    public boolean remove(int index);

    /**
     * Retrieving a question using an index
     * @param index
     * @return the question if index is valid, null otherwise.
     */
    public IQuestion getQuestion(int index);

    /**
     * Return the number of questions in this test set.
     * @return number of questions.
     */
    public int size();
}
```

Comment: the method's decleration in the interface is different, thus when you implemented `public boolean add(Question question);` you havn't overriden `public boolean add(IQuestion question);` and an abstract interface requires you to implement all of it's methods (or be abstract yourself). Either change the parameter in the argument or perhaps make it a `T implements IQuestion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change your list of questions to use the type IQuestion:

```
ArrayList<IQuestion> test = new ArrayList<IQuestion>();
```

Then change the method declaration:

```
public boolean add(IQuestion q){
    try{
        test.add(q);
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```